# Update images in table keeping the old ones

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms, file-upload

I got 12 images and i want to update/edit them with a form. I choose to update one or more but not all of them, but keep the old image name in database.

I tried the following code but when i update one or two images, it's not keeping the old ones and the table field is null.

```
foreach($_FILES['more_images']['name'] as $key => $post_image) {
        $getOld_ImageName = mysql_query("SELECT `image` FROM `more_images` WHERE `car_id` = '$id' AND `key` = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
        $getOld_Image = mysql_fetch_array($getOld_ImageName);
        $more_imageOld = $getOld_Image['image'];

        if (isset($post_image)) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['more_images']['name'][$key];
            $file_tmp  = $_FILES['more_images']['tmp_name'][$key];

            if($file_name == $more_imageOld) {
                $updateMore_Images = mysql_query("UPDATE `more_images` SET `image` = '$more_imageOld' WHERE `car_id` = '$id' AND `key` = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$uploaddir/$file_name");
                $updateMore_Images = mysql_query("UPDATE `more_images` SET `image` = '$file_name' WHERE `car_id` = '$id' AND `key` = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        } else {
            if ($key == $getOld_Image['key']) {
                $post_image = $more_imageOld;
                $updateMore_Images = mysql_query("UPDATE `more_images` SET `image` = '$post_image' WHERE `car_id` = '$id' AND `key` = '$key'") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
```

The `$_FILE` returns the new image names and blank on images that im keeping.

```
0 = 
1 = 4061857_1_b.jpg
2 = 4061857_2_b.jpg
3 = 4061857_3_b.jpg
4 = 4061857_4_b.jpg
5 = 4061857_5_b.jpg
6 = 
7 = 
8 = 
9 = 
10 = 
11 =
```

In other words im trying to update the table and where every `$key` is blank to keep the previous image name in the table as it was.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `if (isset($post_image))` to `if (!empty($post_image))` and it worked.